# Does an English translation of Bombelli's L'Algebra exist?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, translations

I'm looking for an English translation of Rafael Bombelli's L'Algebra.  From what I can tell after having searched the usual corners of the web, it doesn't exist, but I'm asking here just in case.

I'm particularly interested in his analysis of Cardano/Tartaglia/Ferro's methods for cubics and how they relate to complex numbers, so if there's a decently comprehensive history book covering that, that might be suitable. (For whatever it's worth, I currently have C. Boyer's *A History of Mathematics* and P. Nahin's *An Imaginary Tale*, but I'm looking for something a little more focused to accompany those.)

Comment: For a study, see: Roy Wagner, [The natures of numbers in and around Bombelli’s L’algebra](http://www2.mta.ac.il/~rwagner/publications/the%20natures%20of%20numbers.pdf), AHES (2010) as well as Roy Wagner, [The geometry of the unknown: Bombelli's algebra linearia](http://www2.mta.ac.il/~rwagner/publications/geometry%20of%20the%20unknown.pdf) (2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

González-Velasco ([2011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1243.01002)) has a nice dozen pages on *L’Algebra* (§3.3). His preface (p. x) says there has been no translation.

Comment: Bombelli's *L'Algebra* is also discussed on pp. 17-19 of Stedall's [**From Cardano's Great Art to Lagrange's Reflections: Filling a Gap in the History of Algebra**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3037190922). Stedall's book, by the way, is a book that anyone interested in this general topic should have. See, for example, my extensive excerpts from her book in my answer to [History of the theory of equations: John Colson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493016/history-of-the-theory-of-equations-john-colson).